# Spacing of Formula Gets Weird with an Underbrace on One of the Terms

Tags: beamer, spacing, equations, underbrace

So, I just needed an underbrace in a formula in a Beamer presentation and ended up with some weird spacing between the two plus signs. Any clues how to fix? I looked online already for solutions but haven't found one.

Here's the code:

```
\begin{block}{Second stage:}
\centering $Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \widehat{D_i}+ \underbrace{\delta(score_i)}_\text{\parbox{4cm}{\centering Continuous\\[-4pt] function}}+\epsilon_i$
\end{block}
```

And here's how it looks.[image]

Comment: With `\parbox{4cm}` you are requesting `4cm` of horizontal space and that is what you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `\substack`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{Second stage:}
    \begin{equation*}
      Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \hat{D}_i + \underbrace{\delta(\text{score}_i)}_{\substack{\text{Continuous} \\ \text{function}}} + \epsilon_i
    \end{equation*}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]